# One key MenuItem.setAccelerator()

Tags: java, keyboard-shortcuts, menuitem, javafx-8

I want to set one-key `MenuItem` accerelator. I know how to do this for `KeyCombination`, e.g:

```
MenuItem.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.S, 
KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN));
```

..but I'm stuck on one-key shortcut implementation, for example for `F5`, or `ALT` keys.

I know, that I can get most of the one-key shortcut's functionality by using `MenuItem.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>());` method, but I prefer to avoid this, and also, I like `accelerator`'s text label on the right of related `MenuItem`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the other constructor for KeyCodeCombination, for example like that:

```
MenuItem.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.S, KeyCombination.ModifierValue.ANY, KeyCombination.ModifierValue.ANY, KeyCombination.ModifierValue.ANY, KeyCombination.ModifierValue.ANY, KeyCombination.ModifierValue.ANY));
```

Comment: This solution does not allow e.g. for use of "ALT" key.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to use modifier key (like "CTRL", "ALT", "SHIFT") as an accelerator and it makes sense because those keys are not meant to be used alone but with another key in order to make a combination.  For that case, you'll have to go with a keyPressed Listener.